# How to check status of storm in java?

Tags: java, apache-storm

Now I have configured storm cluster on my local machine. Now I know that before starting storm you have to start nimbus then supervisor and at last ui by storm commands.

Now I am writing a Java program and i want to check the status of my storm cluster that either it is working or not.

Like:

```
if(stormWorking()){
//do this
}
else{
//do this
}
```

Now how can I check that my storm cluster is running successfully or not?

Comment: You want to check the status of Storm inside your topology or from independent application?

Comment: Scenario is Storm cluster running on my machine. Topology has been submitted. Now using an independent Java program I want to check whether storm is running or not. I dont want to check it inside the topology class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *monit[1]* daemon philosophy and check .pid files. Just check each Storm process need to work properly:

> cat /etc/monit.d/storm

```
check process storm-nimbus with pidfile /var/run/storm/storm-nimbus.pid
start program = "/sbin/service storm-nimbus start"
stop program = "/sbin/service storm-nimbus stop"

check process storm-supervisor with pidfile /var/run/storm/storm-supervisor.pid
start program = "/sbin/service storm-supervisor start"
stop program = "/sbin/service storm-supervisor stop"

check process storm-ui with pidfile /var/run/storm/storm-ui.pid
start program = "/sbin/service storm-ui start"
stop program = "/sbin/service storm-ui stop"

check process storm-logviewer with pidfile /var/run/storm/storm-logviewer.pid
start program = "/sbin/service storm-logviewer start"
stop program = "/sbin/service storm-logviewer stop"
```

[1] Monit is a small Open Source utility for managing and monitoring Unix systems http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer for this but you can try out following few options to check if it helps :

1) Look for storm process Id by doing some thing like `ps -ef | grep StormNimbus` 
If it exists you can tell for sure that the service is up.

2) Create a `Thrift` client using Java and look for `NimbusUpTime` using the `get_nimbus_uptime_secs` method provided by the `ClusterSummary` class .. a very simple sample code can look like below

```
    Map conf = Utils.readStormConfig();
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "xx.x.x.xxx");
    Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(conf).getClient();

    // get the cluster summery object
    ClusterSummary csummery = client.getClusterInfo();

    // look for nimbus up time 
    int uptime = csummery.get_nimbus_uptime_secs();
```

if the uptime has a non-zero value then your cluster is up and running.

Comment: Your code is not working. It keeps on giving connection refused exception.

Comment: can u actually see if storm is running? can u see the storm ui?

Comment: No I have turned off storm. Its not running. I want to test failure use case. if(!stormWorking()). I want to get in the body of this if. So no need to start storm.

Comment: Actually the 3rd line of client gives exceptiom

Comment: an exception while attempting to create a thrift client might indicate the process is not up, however as i mentioned earlier this might not be a full proof solution, did you try running a shell script to check if the process id exists for storm?

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169413/error-thread-threadmain-5-main-died

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is create a shell script that checks for the ports that are used by Storm. If any of the ports are missing, then you will now that you have a problem with your system.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169413/error-thread-threadmain-5-main-died